# Как узнать параметр owner_id для функции likes.getList?

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте. Такой вопрос. Хочу для некоторого списка страниц узнать количество лайков и репостов. Использую для этого, соответственно, метод getList. Например:

```
api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=sitepage&owner_id=2925955&page_url=lenta.ru/articles/2014/09/24/duglas&filter=likes
```

Но как мне узнать по-нормальному значение `owner_id`? Чтобы вот так вручную посмотреть результат, я нажимаю F12, нахожу элемент виджета и смотрю там в коде этот параметр, но нужно же всё автоматизировать? Как мне это сделать? Парсить код страницы? Или я вообще ерундой занимаюсь и это можно сделать проще?

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, поможет вот этот 
[ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/367177/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5#369058).

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы, только так. Метод сделан для владельцев ресурса/виджета, и вы поступаете как крутой хакер, выясняя owner_id.

Ещё один момент: если владельцы меняли `owner_id` виджета, или `item_id` объекта, то счётчик лайков сбрасывается и начинает собираться с нуля снова. Т.е. например, они могут раз в неделю сбрасывать его, учтя у себя где-то для статистики предыдущие лайки.

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись и за подсказку: про смену id и сброс счетчика не знал. Ладно, придётся тогда как-то изловчиться. Ещё видел, что количество репостов можно собирать с помощью http://vk.com/share.php?act=count&index=1&url=, но этот метод часто выдает неактуальные значения счетчика...