# Как составить список, кто репостнул новость с сайта к себе на стену вконтакте?

Tags: ajax, php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

На неком сайте есть функционал "поделиться новостью".

```
http://vk.com/share.php?url=http://{нужный мне сайт}
```

Как средствами API или curl-запросом отследить, что реально сделан репост?

Comment: Насколько помню, у репост можно отслеживать так же, как и лайк.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**facebook**: graph.facebook.com/http://habrahabr.ru/post/149709/

```
{
id: "http://habrahabr.ru/post/149709/",
shares: 3
}
```

**twitter**: urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://habrahabr.ru/post/149709/

```
{
count: 29,
url: "http://habrahabr.ru/post/149709/"
}
```

**vk**: vk.com/share.php?act=count&index=1&url=http://habrahabr.ru/post/149709/

```
VK.Share.count(1, 9); // 9 - count
```

[Тема на toaster](https://toster.ru/q/22850)

[Еще один сайт](http://creograf.ru/post/social-like)

Comment: Хороший ответ, только ОП спрашивает про «список тех, кто репостнул» – id'шники, а не общее кол-во.

Comment: id - у меня в базе хранятся,  поэтому даже эта зацепка мне поможет, спасибо всем.

Answer (score 0):

[Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/366455/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80-owner-id-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-likes-getlist)

Если интересует не лайк, а именно репост — как костыль, поиск самого ВК по этой ссылке тоже что-то покажет.